# C pthread_create and join outside the main function

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int ids = 0;
sem_t sync;
int idx = 0;
int count = 0;


void * add2(void * p_idx) {
    int * tmp = (int *) p_idx;
    int id = ids++;
    sem_wait(&sync);
    (*tmp)++;
    count++;
    printf("executed by %d, number is %d\n", id, *tmp);
    sem_post(&sync);
}

int createThreadOutsideMain() {
    pthread_t *outsideMain = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t));
    pthread_create(outsideMain, NULL, add2, (void *) &idx);
    pthread_join(*outsideMain, NULL);
    return 0;
}

void * add(void * p_idx) {
    int * tmp = (int *) p_idx;
    int id = ids++;
    while(count < 10) {
        if (count % 2 == 0) {
            continue;
        }
        sem_wait(&sync);
        (*tmp)++;
        count++;
        printf("executed by %d, number is %d\n", id, *tmp);
        sem_post(&sync);
    }
    createThreadOutsideMain();
}


int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    pthread_t insideMain1, insideMain2;
    sem_init(&sync, 0, 1);
    pthread_create(&insideMain1, NULL, add, (void *) &idx);
    pthread_create(&insideMain2, NULL, add, (void *) &idx);
    pthread_join(insideMain1, NULL);
    pthread_join(insideMain2, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

I am a newer to C and pthread libary, I ran into a situation. Generally describled as below.
I want to create threads and join the thread outside main function during runtime according to the input, so here I use an if statemnt to create a new
thread if count is odd number.
i want all the threads using the same semaphore &sync, but when I run the code, it just stuck,
i want to the output like this

executed by 0, number is 0

executed by 1, number is 1

executed by 2, number is 2

executed by 3, number is 3

executed by 0, number is 4

executed by 4, number is 5

executed by 2, number is 6

executed by 0, number is 7
...

is this idea possible? if so, where is my problem, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First fix the below while loop and try again. This loop will indefinite as condition in if will always true. The reason is, while you are calling the `add` method from the first thread you are passing the parameter with zero. First it lock the `mutex` and stuck in the while loop for ever and your second thread is waiting for the lock to be unlock. Hence your application is finally stuck in the loop for ever. Pass the parameter as 1 and check what happened.

```
  while(count < 10) {
    if (count % 2 == 0) {// value of (0 % 2) == 0 always and this loop will continue for ever
        continue;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (count % 2 == 0) {
            continue;
        }
```

replace above code with this because if `if statement` is true count value is not changing and `continue` statement is taking to infinite loop

```
if (count % 2 == 0) {
            count++;
            continue;
        }
```